# Inline keyboard callback_query setup in Google Apps Script Telegram bot

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I've managed to figure out how to attach an inline button to message from my Telegram bot. I'm not sure how to make this button actually do something.

I have a simple invoice table in my Google Spreadsheet. I manually connected a Form to it, through which managers can request some financial transactions.

My perfect scenario: on every new form submit bot sends me a message with all the transaction's data. It already works perfectly *(I'm using variables from form responses in combination with `sendMessage` and `UrlFetchApp.fetch`)*.

Now, I want to attach a functional button that will delete the particular message it's connected to and then send me a "Transaction completed" message.

My inline keyboard code excerpt:

```
'{"inline_keyboard":[[{"text":"Del","callback_data":"delete_message"}]]}'
```

I use most primitive webhook:

```
function setWebhook() {
var url = telegramUrl + "/setWebhook?url=" + webAppUrl;
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
}
```

And I have a `doPost` function for just replying to /start command (if some manager got lost in space and time):
function doPost(e) {

```
var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
var chat_id = contents.message.from.id; 
var fname = contents.message.from.first_name;
var text = (""+fname +", this bot is for notification only, fill the form located on our website."); 
sendMessage(chat_id,text)
}
```

I've Googled a lot, and tried some solutions, but it seems like my callback listening still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same thing. Your script crashes when you click the button on the line:

```
var chat_id = contents.message.from.id;
```

You should handle in doPost something like that:

```
var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
if (contents.message) {
  let text = contents.message.text
  let id = contents.message.chat.id
  ...
}
if (contents.callback_query) {
   let id = contents.callback_query.from.id
   let data = contents.callback_query.data
   let text = contents.callback_query.message.text
   ...
}
```